# how to create memory card in android emulator?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Virtually create sd card in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063494/virtually-create-sd-card-in-eclipse)

how to create memory card in android emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the android tool or mksdcard to create a sdcard image, meanwhile the Eclipse ADT plugin also asks you if sdcard is needed when creating a new AVD.

Command line option for creating a sdcard image using android tool:

```
android create avd -n <avd_name> -t <targetID> -c <size>[K|M]
```

Command line option for creating a sdcard image using mksdcard:

```
mksdcard <size> <file>
```

By the way you can find answers to these common questions in [Android Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#creatingm), also Google is your friend :)