# Virtually create sd card in eclipse

Tags: android

I wanted to know how to virtually create sd card in the emulator. Also I wanted to know where the app is really installed on the device.Is it in sd card or in internal memory..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find your app stored location using DDMS in Eclipse. Usually you app will under 
data->data->

Comment: so how can i put some images to the virtual sd card and see it through the emulator

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The above is answering your question related to your emulator SD card.

For installed app location follow this link:

[Difference between Emulator and Real Device for Installed applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790153/difference-between-emulator-and-real-device-for-installed-applications)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SD Card functionality in your Emulator then add new hardware SD Card Support. This option is avaible when you created new avd.